# Can't get JHipster version update

Tags: jhipster

I tried to get JHipster version updated from 6.8.0 to 6.9.0. But my Node.js was too old for the task. Following some online instruction, I get Node.js to v14.2.0. (shown in the output of "nvm ls"). After running

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

I have the following result:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/home/oem/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/jhipster -> 
/home/oem/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js
+ generator-jhipster@6.9.0
updated 1 package in 14.38s
```

But,

```
jhipster --version
Using JHipster version installed globally
5.4.2
```

I have a look at all Node versions on my PC.

```
ls -l /home/oem/.nvm/versions/node/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 7 oem oem 4096 Aug  4  2018 v10.0.0
drwxrwxr-x 6 oem oem 4096 May 17 13:38 v14.2.0
drwxrwxr-x 7 oem oem 4096 Aug  4  2018 v8.9.0
```

JHipster somehow picks a wrong version of Node, I guess.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Well 14.x is the current (unstable) version we recommend to use an LTS  version. Anyway, I suspect a mis configuration of your PATH

Comment: Try `nvm install 12.16.3`, which is the latest LTS version. To see what version you are using, run `nvm current`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After running the installation command in my home directory, I run the jhipster vue blueprint in a project directory without a problem. When I run jdl file import, I get a complaint about old Node version again. I run the installation command again in the project directory. Do the import again. This time it works. But the reactive isn't ready for SQL.